# How to use scrapy with SFTP

Tags: python, scrapy, sftp

Is it possible to use scrapy to download files from an SFTP server? If not, can you suggest how to extend scrapy to do so, maybe with a custom middleware?

Comment: I mean does a scrapy spider natively support SFTP URLs, not whether python in general has support.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [scrapy-feedexporter-sftp](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-feedexporter-sftp/).

I’ve never used myself, so I don’t know whether or not it works, but even if it does not work it should serve you as a starting point for your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a quick proof of concept for doing this kind of thing that I put [here](https://github.com/further-reading/scrapy-sftp). The ELI5 is I made a download handler that activates for any sftp url. You add your SFTP server details + login to your settings and it will return a http.Response object with the contents of the file as bytes in the response.body.

It's kind of hacky so may not be suitable for large files and/or large numbers of files.